# Crontab - Sending StdErr to email and stdOut to log file

Tags: linux, cron, scripting, shell

In my crontab, I'm trying to send stdout to log file and stderr to email account using a custom subject title.

I've tried many solutions without achieving my initial goal, let me explain:

**First method: using MAILTO**

```
MAILTO=my.email@address.com
*/1 * * * * /my/script.sh > /my/file_stdout.log
```

This send stdout to log file and error to email, but the drawback is that I can't figure out how to update the email subject and what I have in consequence is **Subject: Cron  /my/script.sh > /my/file_stdout.log**.

**Second method: using mail**

I've playing arround with many ways of using mail but none of them works like I want:

```
*/1 * * * * /my/script.sh > /my/file_stdout.log 2>&1; [ $? != 0 ] && mail -s "Subject here" my.email@address.com < /my/file_stdout.log
```

another one :

```
*/1 * * * * /my/script.sh > /my/file_stdout.log 2>&1 || mail -s "Subject here" my.email@address.com < /my/file_stdout.log
```

another one :

```
*/1 * * * * /my/script.sh 2>&1 | tee /my/file_stdout.log | mail -s "Subject here" my.email@address.com < /my/file_stdout.log
```

another one:

```
*/1 * * * * OUTPUT=`/my/script.sh 2>&1` || echo "$OUTPUT" | mail -s "Subject here" my.email@address.com
```

Also I've noticed that or operator `||` doesn't work in my crontab, I even change the shell of crontab to /bin/bash ( by adding SHELL=/bin/bash variable).

I'm on Redhat entreprise server, and don't have Admin access so I can't install tools like chronic !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it to work, and found the issue with `||` operator, the script was always returning code 0, so now I've added explicitly a `return` statement at the end of the script, and now work as expected :

```
*/1 * * * * (/my/script.sh > /my/file_stdout.log 2>&1) || mail -s "Subject here" my.email@address.com < /my/file_stdout.log
```